# Grafana Alert Templating

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am struggling to include values into my alerting template
(Using Grafana 9.03 with classic condition alerting)

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPwG6.png)

[Alert Evaluation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt9Vx.png)

I tried to use {{ $values.B0 }} which works but only displaying the value. I want to use the Tag "Limit" for example "ImportStatNSC4903"

I did some more tries with:

```
{{ $values.B0.Limit }}
{{ $values.B0.labels }}
{{ $labels }}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I am struggling to include values into my alerting template. I want a summery that tells me clearly why this alert was triggered

For example:

> Limit ImportStatNSC4903  is outside the defined Boundaries